# Format number to string according to template number

Tags: python, numbers, format

I would like to display a number according to the precision of another template/example number.

Like, having `example_number = 0.0001` and being able to do `format_fp_digits_like(example_number, another_number)` ; with `another_number=10.12345` I would get `10.1234`.

This is what I tried so far:

```py
import math

def format_fp_digits_like(template_number, number):
    n_digits = len(str(int(number)))
    if '.' in str(template_number):
        n_fp_digits = len(str(math.modf(template_number)[0]).split(".")[-1])
    else:
        n_fp_digits = 0
    fs = "{:"+f"{n_digits}.{n_fp_digits}f"+"}"
    return fs.format(number)

assert format_fp_digits_like(0.0001, 16.12345) == "16.1234"
assert format_fp_digits_like(1, 16.123) == "16"
assert format_fp_digits_like(0.1, 8.5) == "8.5"
```

It works, but I find it clumsy. There is probably a better way ?

Comment: this seems somewhat fragile!  what should it do if the template looks like `"0.12e3"` or it's given `"fail"`?  why not use conventional `width`, `precision` and `type` arguments?

Comment: @SamMason I have another number as "template", no width, precision or type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use string formatting:

```
def rounder(template_number, number):
    return ('{0:.%sf}' % len(str(template_number).split('.')[-1])).format(number)


rounder(0.0001, 10.12345)

'10.1235'
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, more or less but I am tired - thanks for your answer. I had to return "int(number)" in case "template_number" is an integer to pass my small test suite ;) I used `if float(template_number).is_integer(): return int(number)`, else your code